# Django - filtering related objects in "backward" relationships

Tags: django, filter, models, relationship

I've been working on some models with "backward" relationships. I started wondering... What if I want to filter some results?

I've got two models:

```
Model A:
 name
 image
 date 

Model B:
 ForeignKey to Model A
 name
 date
```

To access model A I use:
    p = A.objects.all().order_by('-date')

and I pass that to template.

In template:

```
{% for n in model_a.all %}
  {% for item in n.modelb_set.all %}

   <li>{{item.name}}</li>

  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get all backward related objects for model A and thats fine.

Now what if I want to filter some results from that query?

I was thinking of iteration in a View by:

```
p = A.objects.all().order_by('-date')

for n in p:
    for x in n.modelb_set.filter(date_lte=""):
    ls = []
    ls.append[x]
```

How do I pass that to the template and get what I got earlier (unfiltered view) but now with filtered results?

Comment: This feels like you're mixing representation and business logic. It's probably best to implement a manager that encapsulates that. You could also iterate over a queryset of B and filter it by some criteria in A

Comment: Thanks for response I'll remember that :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to add a method to your model. It would be easier to illustrate with a real world model example, but the gist is:

```
class ModelA:
    ...
    def filtered_modelb_set(self):
        return self.modelb_set.filter(...)
    ...
```

Then, in your template, you just call that method instead:

```
{% for n in model_a.all %}
    {% for item in n.filtered_modelb_set %}

    <li>{{item.name}}</li>

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Great anwser! I never thought of that and I just came up with weird ideas for that problem :)